# Is it efficient to maintain the class-hierarchy strictly in AS3, or it is better to put everything in one place?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, structure

Which one is the most efficient way of designing complex, strictly OOP AS3 software?

Lets say, I have this hierarchy: main class -> userinterface class -> menu class -> button class

Which one is the better?

- Separating **only the main** parts of the code into classes, like "telecom", "userinterface", "externalinterface", ect..., and adding the subparts, like "menu", then adding the "buttons" to the "menu", **from the** "userinterface" class with `addChild()`.

**or**

- Also separating the main parts of the software, **but also separating the subparts**.: I do not define the buttons inside **"userinterface"**, and `appendChild()` them to the "menu" that I also define in the "userinterface", but rather, I define buttons **inside the "menu" class**, so I dont have to put dozens of code in one class (in this case "userinterface"), thus making it more structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it efficient to maintain the class-hierarchy strictly in AS3, or it
>   is better to put everything in one place?

It's rarely a good idea to put everything in one place. Also, I don't think this relates directly to class hierarchy (as in parent-child classes) - I think you meant hierarchy as in "who creates what".

My own preference is to have a good amount of separation and decoupling between classes, and then assemble them in one place. This "divide and conquer" approach is essential to good OOP design.

> Which one is the most efficient way of designing complex, strictly OOP
>   AS3 software?

For this general question, I give you a general pointer to the MVC pattern. It's a widely know architecture for structuring the codebase of interactive applications, and it works quite well with AS3.

You can learn the key concepts [here (PDF)](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/pdfs/ora_as3_design_patterns_ch12.pdf) and then try to apply to your situation. You'll learn to identify the "roles" in your code and therefore be able to organize the code in a much better way.